# AnyLogic: How to make AGV wait/sleep separately using event

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have 10 AGVs(TransporterFleet) moving on a guided path. I created functions to return random time and duration for AGV's error. All functions and event were created in AGV, not main() because I want each AGV to have their own random error and error duration.

**Problem:** The AGV does move as if nothing happens, same speed, no sleep.

**Expect:** Each AGV should stop when model time = nextTimeToFailure and stop for nextFailureDuration seconds. When an AGV stops, sleep function should not stop other AGVs.

**Current set up:**

timeToFailure()

```
double timeToFailure = exponential(0, 60, 0, 10);
return timeToFailure;
```

failureDuration()

```
double duration = exponential(0, 15, 0, 3);
return duration;
```

Then I have an event to trigger on condition: time() == nextTimeToFailure

```
if(nextTimeToFailure == 0){
System.out.println("nextFailureDuration is 0 ");
    nextTimeToFailure = time() + timeToFailure();
    nextFailureDuration = failureDuration();    
}

setSpeed(reducedSpeed()); //reduceSpeed() function return 0
rectangle.setFillColor(red);
try {
    Thread.sleep((long)nextFailureDuration);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("got interrupted!");
}

nextTimeToFailure = Double.NaN;
nextFailureDuration = Double.NaN;

nextTimeToFailure = time() + timeToFailure();
nextFailureDuration = failureDuration();
    
rectangle.setFillColor(lime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER use condition-based events at all, they work differently than you think (fairly advanced concepts under the hood).

Instead, simply setup a statechart or Dynamic Event to regularly trigger every `timeToFailure`.

For Dynamic Event:

1. drag it into your AGV agent type, name it `myDE`
2. on startup code of the AGV, call `create_myDE(timeToFailure(), MINUTE);` (or whatever time unit `timeToFailure()` returns in)
3. in the DE, write your usual code and compute the `nextTimeToFailure`
4. at the end of the DE code, make it re-call itself using create_myDE(nextTimeToFailure, MINUTE);`

This will recreate failure events again and again, and they will trigger 100% "on time"

However, the state-chart approach is a more visual and elegant way, check the example models, there are tons that show how to use it for failures.

Or use the "Downtime" block

Comment: I'm very new to AnyLogic. Could you explain a bit more what do you mean when you say '2. on startup code of the AGV'?

Comment: your agent type AGV has properties. One of them is the "on startup" code. Best do all AnyLogic step-by-step tutorials first to grasp some fundamentals, tbh. DynamicEvents are a fairly advanced concept by themselves...

Comment: Thank you. I managed to make DynamicEvents work but when an AGV sleeps, the whole model stops. Is there another function to put an AGV to sleep for a period of time?

Comment: yes, state charts. But if the entire model stops, you are doing something wrong :) Feel free to open new questions with specific info, some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow